# How to Display Database Data in TextBox?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to display data from database in ASP.Net TextBox.
But ASP.Net Textbox doesn't have DataSource and DataSourceID.
I used ADO.Net Disconnect Approach to connect and retrieve data from MSSQL 2008 database.
So how can I do that problem?

Comment: What "data" are you trying to display, and can you not use the `Text` property of TextBox?

Comment: It's not...
I mean...when retrieve data from database , we can connect with DataSource or DataSourceID (GridView,ListBox) such as...
But Textbox doesn't have DataSourceID or DataSource..
When i trying to connect as below

txt.Text=dataset.Table["Table"]; 

TextBox display "Table" Text...

Comment: That's because you have to tell your application what data is "interesting". You normally don't display a *whole* table in a textbox, but rather some specific information that you perhaps want to edit, and then do an update against the database again. Using a Dataset you can retrieve some cell from the table and display *that*, instead of all of it. That's why I asked, it's somewhat of an odd question to me.. :-/

Answer (score 1):

This will get data from a table named "Table" which could be referenced numerically instead
It will get data from the first row of the table (row 0)
and it will get data from the first column (column 0)
The column could be named if you want, or you could use one of the other six overloads.

```
txt.Text = (string)ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[0][0];
```

I would personally set a memory variable to the value and then assign it to the text box.
And, I would check to see if there were any rows retrieved
Something like this

```
string myValue;

if (ds.["Table"].Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      //You must cast the value because it is an object
       myValue = (string)ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[0][0];
   }
   else
   {
       myValue = "No Data found";
   }

   txt.Text = myValue;
```

Of course, if your are only retrieving one table, you could use a DataTable instead of a DataSet.
A DataTable is "lighter" weight than a DataSet.

Hope this helps

Harvey Sather